Document Intelligence - 404 not found, endpoint issue?
We are trying to use Microsoft document intelligence via the API, and we are running into some challenging issues. We have tried 3 deployments:

North Central US (key is short - looks like a GUID without dashes)
South Central US (we created the deployment from WITHIN the Document Intelligence Studio, because we were trying to create a Neural model from our North Central resource and neural is not supported, so we created it directly from the create project screen in document intelligence studio.
South Central US (key is longer - is 84 characters long)

The endpoints look a bit different between the resources as well - in the azure portal, in both the overview and keys/endpoint screen.

The North central endpoint looks like: https://[resource name].cognitiveservices.azure.com/
The South central resource we created from document intelligence studio endpoint looks like: https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/
The South central resource we created manually - endpoint looks like: https://[resource name].cognitiveservices.azure.com/

It seems that creating the document intelligence azure resource through the document intelligence studio creates it in such a way that the endpoint is not set up correctly, as it's not usable. However, manually creating the same thing in the same region (south central) gives us what appears to be a more "correct" URL, but also fails with the same error.
Also note - we are using the DocumentIntelligenceClient rather than the DocumentAnalysisClient as it seems to be the most current client to be used, per Microsoft:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/documentintelligence/Azure.AI.DocumentIntelligence/MigrationGuide.md
"The client DocumentIntelligenceClient has replaced DocumentAnalysisClient."
We are able to use the Base64 content option to call the prebuilt-layout model against the north central endpoint, but if we use either of the south central endpoints, we get error:
Resource not found
Status: 404 (Not Found)
ErrorCode: 404
So - we know our code is working, but not sure if there's something wrong with south central, something wrong with the way the resource endpoint was configured, or if the DocumentIntelligenceClient is not working properly against south central, or what exactly the issue is.

Have you configured for both South Central resources with appropriate permissions and roles. because Sometimes resources created directly with general portal configurations.

I believe so. Do you just mean the “access control (IAM)” tab? I am a contributor to the entire resource group so inheritance applies and I have contributor to this resource as well.
Is there any other place to apply permissions?

If the South Central resources have any network restrictions or IP allowlists configured, they may block access, even with correct permissions.

Check if there’s a virtual network or firewall configuration under the “Networking” tab on the South-Central US resource.

Firewalls and virtual networks is set to "Allow access from All networks"

We are able to get it to work with the older Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis library.
Ironically, the north central US region with does not support the neural models works with the newer DocumentIntelligence library, but the south central US region, which does support the neural model (and therefore seems to be a newer version of document intelligence) only works with the OLDER FormsRecognizer library.
It's been challenging to say the least - there are 3 different libraries/clients and different versions in azure based on region, the compatibility is confusing and buggy.
